# What is the syntax for editing a label's constraints/position in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to set up a conditional that will change the location of a particular label in the view in swift. I figure I will put the change of the label's position in the `viewDidLoad()`, but if I put in this modification to move the label's constraints based on the conditional, will it (upon being reloaded) have the label in the position/constraint set manually on the storyboard? Or would I need to code that position back in?

```
if condition x{
//move label position
} else{
//keep the position set in storyboard, even upon reload
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Storyboard will not be changed.

Answer (score -1):

```
///I have created the button & label on storyboard. And changing the position of label when button is clicked. I have added the constraint to the label on storyboard & created the outlet of top constraint.

var flag = true
@IBOutlet weak var UiLblConstraintTop: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBAction func ChangePositionOfLabel(sender: UIButton) {

    if flag{
        self.UiLblConstraintTop.constant = 300
    }
    else{
        self.UiLblConstraintTop.constant = 50
    }
    flag = !flag
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```